Explicit expression for a function in number theory
In their paper "Moyenne de certains fonctions arithmétiques sur les entiers friables", Tenenbaum and Wu proved that for the case of the function $\beta$ which is the indicator function of integers that are sums of two squares, there exists a continuous function $\lambda$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\lambda(0)>0$ and
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \beta(n)= \int_0^{1/2} x^{1-t} \frac{\lambda(t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt+O\left(\frac{x}{L(x)^c}\right)\quad (x\geq 3).$$
Where $$L(x)=\exp\left(\frac{\log(x)^{3/5}}{\log_2(x)^{1/5}}\right)$$ and $c$ is a suitable positive constant. This result is obtained by using the Selberg–Delange method. My question is how to obtain an explicit expression for $\lambda$ and how to find a good bound for the sums on the right side, i.e. on $\sum_{n\le x}\beta(n)$.

The function $\lambda(s)$ is given by $\sqrt{s F(1-s)}/(\pi (1-s))$ where $F(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \beta(s)/n^s$ (this definition relies on $F(s)\sqrt{1-s}$ having an analytic continuation to, say, $|s|<1$). The integral on the RHS enjoys an asymptotic expansion that starts with $Kx/\sqrt{\log x} (1+O(1/\log x))$ for a positive constant $K$ known as the Landau-Ramanujan constant. This constant is essentially $\lambda(0)$ (maybe divided by a simple factor such as $\pi$).

@OfirGorodetsky Did you mean $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n\ge 1} \frac{\beta(n)}{n^s}$ (i.e. $\beta(n)$ versus $\beta(s)$)? Do you know if $F(s)$ can be expressed in terms of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$?

@StevenClark Yes and yes. One can write $F(s)$ as $\sqrt{\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(s)}$ times $G(s)$, where $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}(s)$ is the Dedekind zeta function of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, itself factoring as $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi_{-4})$, and $G$ is given by a Dirichlet series converging absolutely and bounded in $\Re(s)\ge \tfrac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$. In fact, one can write $G(s)$ as an infinite product involving $\zeta(2^i s)$ and $L(2^i s, \chi_{-4})$ with $i\ge 1$. I intend to post an answer later on.

@OfirGorodetsky Thanks, I'm looking forward to reading your answer!

I believe $\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \beta(n)$ corresponds to OEIS entry A102548 which gives links to a few more related papers.

@StevenClark have you an idea how to express the sums over integers written as sum of three squares?

OEIS Entry A071377 gives number of positive integers $\le n$ which are the sum of $3$ squares, which is the partial sum of OEIS Entry A071374 (with its zeroth term omitted). OEIS Entry A071374 is defned as $0$ iff $n$ is of the form $4^a, (8 k+7)$, otherwise 1.

@steven Clark is there an explicit or asymptotic formula for the sum $\sum_{n\leq x, n=a^2+b^2+c^2} 1$ ?

I haven't been able to find an explicit or asymptotic formula, but the growth of $$\sum\limits_{\substack{n\leq x \ n=a^2+b^2}} 1$$ and $$\sum\limits_{\substack{n\leq x \ n=a^2+b^2+c^2}} 1$$ both seem to be nearly linear.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/479974/sum-over-three-squares

"My question is ... how to find a good bound for the sums on the right side ...." There is no sum on the right side. Presumably, "right" should be "left".

This result may have been known to Landau. In 1908, Landau proved that
$$\sum_{n \le x} \beta(n) \sim K \frac{x}{\sqrt{\log x}}$$
holds as $x \to \infty$, where $K$ is the Landau-Ramanujan constant given by $$K = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \bmod 4}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
It is named so because in Ramanujan's first letter to Hardy in 1913, he stated the same result (without proof).
Let $D_{\beta}(s):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \beta(n)/n^s$. Recall that
$$D_{\beta}(s) = (1-2^{-s})^{-1}\prod_{p \equiv 1 \bmod 4} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \bmod 4} (1-p^{-2s})^{-1}$$
holds for $\Re s > 1$. Hence
$$D_{\beta}(s) = \sqrt{\zeta(s) L(s,\chi_{-4})} G(s)\quad \text{ for }\quad G(s) := \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-2^{-s}}} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \bmod 4} (1-p^{-2s})^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
It is not hard to see that $G(s)$ converges absolutely for $\Re s \ge 1/2+\varepsilon$ and defines a bounded, analytic function there. Moreover, $\sqrt{L(s,\chi_{-4})}$ has an analytic continuation within any zero-free region, and the same goes for $\sqrt{\zeta(s)(s-1)}$ (since $L(s,\chi_{-4})$ and $\zeta(s)(s-1)$ are entire).
While I haven't checked Landau's paper recently, I would expect it is not difficult to extract from his proof that the following holds:
$$(\star)\, \sum_{n \le x} \beta(n) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{L(\sigma,\chi_{-4})} \sqrt{\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)} G(\sigma)}{(1-\sigma)^{1/2}}\frac{x^{\sigma}}{\sigma}d\sigma + O\left( \frac{x}{L(x)^c}\right)$$
where $L(x)$ is as in your question. In other words, the statement you quote holds with
$$\lambda(t)  := \frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{L(1-t,\chi_{-4})} \sqrt{\zeta(1-t) t}  G(1-t) \frac{1}{1-t}.$$
Three references for $(\star)$ (or very similar statements): Ramachandra's paper, Exercise 21(d) on p. 187 of Montgomery and Vaughan's book "Multiplicative Number Theory I" and Theorem 2.1 of David-Devin-Nam-Schlitt. See Remark 2 in Ramachandra for a discussion of an asymptotic expansion for your integral, as well as the rest of this answer.
Landau's proof is a special case of the Selberg-Delange method, which is why some authors call this method the Landau-Selberg-Delange method.
The error term in $(\star)$ ultimately comes from the zero-free region for $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi_{-4})$. (So strictly speaking, because Landau only had the classical zero-free region, he would only get an error of $O(x \exp(-c\sqrt{\log x}))$.) The error term is much smaller under GRH, see Appendix B2 here.
Observe that $\lambda(0) = G(1)\sqrt{\pi/4}/\pi= K/\sqrt{\pi}$. This is consistent with Landau's result, since
$$\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{1-t} \frac{\lambda(t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\log x}}\int_{0}^{(\log x)/2}e^{-v} \frac{\lambda(v/\log x)}{\sqrt{v}}dv \sim \frac{x}{\sqrt{\log x}} \lambda(0) \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-v} \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v}},$$
and the last integral is $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$. By Taylor-expanding $\lambda$ at $0$, one can obtain an asymptotic expansion for $\sum_{n\le x}\beta(n)$ in descending powers of $\log x$.

To address Steven Clark's question from the comments: Shanks, and independently Flajolet and Vardi, proved that
$$D_{\beta}(s) = \sqrt{\zeta(s)L(s,\chi_{-4})(1-2^{-s})^{-1}}\prod_{k\ge 1} \left( \frac{(1-2^{-2^k s})\zeta(2^ks)}{L(2^k s,\chi_{-4})}\right)^{2^{-k-1}}$$
holds for $\Re s >1$ from which they deduced that
$$K = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\prod_{k\ge 1} \left( \frac{(1-2^{-2^k })\zeta(2^k)}{L(2^k,\chi_{-4})}\right)^{2^{-k-1}}.$$
