Sum over three squares
Let $x$ be a sufficiently large number. Is there an explicit or asymptotic formula for the following sum
$$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n=a^2+b^2+c^2}} 1.$$ Any reference would be helpful.

Every number that is not of the form $4^a(8b + 7)$, $a,b \geq 0$, can be written as the sum of three squares.

Thanks for the information I know that  and I would like to find a formula for that sum.

The number of integers $n\leq x$ that are not the sum of three squares is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{4^k(8\ell+7)\leq x}1
&=\sum_{4^k\leq x/7}\left\lfloor\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{x}{4^k}+1\right)\right\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{4^k\leq x/7}\left(\frac{x}{8\cdot 4^k}+O(1)\right)\\
&=\frac{x}{8}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^k}+O(\log x)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}x+O(\log x).
\end{align*}
Hence the number of integers $n\leq x$ that are the sum of three squares is
$$\frac{5}{6}x+O(\log x).$$
